# Symbology levels are ignored in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, symbology, representation

I have a problem migrating from a ArgGIS 9.3 to a 10 geodatabase (both sde and  file gdb). The symbology levels stored in the 9.3 database are not transferred.

When migrated to ArcGIS 10.0, symbology levels are ordered by alphanumerical order, and not the order assigned by me.

I tried to migrate the data both by copying the featureclass and by upgrading the database -- both with the same dissapointing result: The symbology levels go back to the alphanumerical order of the categories. This is a BIG problem for me, since I have a massive amount of symbology levels in lots of featureclasses each having different representations.

Have any of you similar experiences? More importantly: Is there a fix for this?

Comment: do you try save symbology in a layer . right click your featureclass click save as layer file.then in arcgis 10 load the layerfile : properties=>symbology=>import=>choose your layerfile.maybe it works